# Messed up my active partition

Tags: windows-7, boot, partitioning

I have an HP laptop with HP_RECOVERY partition. I was trying to restore to factory settings. In other words, I wanted to erase everything and have a fresh install (from HP_REVOERY partition) of Windows 7. However, on restart (using F11), it didn't let me repair my OS.

I tried an answer at [HP Forums](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Operating-Systems-and-Software/F11-HP-recovery-doesn-t-boot-into-recovery-partition/td-p/197434)

Now my laptop says "missing operating system" :(

Is there any option to change active partition?

Constraints:

1 - My laptop does not have any kind of disk player (no CD or DVD player)

Comment: I more or less already know the answer to this question, but will your laptop let you boot into cmd prompt by pressing f8 during startup? More than likely it will default to 'no operating system,' but I have to ask. The reason it's throwing that error is because you marked the wrong partition as active, obviously, but the real issue is that the partition you need to reactivate (system reserved) is hidden. As far as I know, you can only get to it through the cmd prompt using <DISKPART>. You may want to find someone with Windows 7 on a stick.

Comment: Hi Josh, thanks for the reply. I have another laptop and USB. I do not have any Windows 7 disk/stick. No my laptop just shows "missing operating system". I can only go in BIOS :(

Comment: Well, I searched the net for a quick an easy way for you to download and create a bootable DOS drive, but given that DOS uses the FAT file system and your drives use NTSF, you wouldn't be able to access your drives that way. The only thing I can tell you is to get ahold of a Windows XP/Vista/7 CD and create a bootable USB drive using [WinToFlash](http://wintoflash.com/home/en/) and then use <DISKPART> cmd line tool to set your active flag. You can also look into what wbouzane wrote below. Best of luck with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can boot from any partition using a boot manager. If you have a flash drive you can download PLOP boot manager from here http://download.plop.at/files/bootmngr/plpbt-5.0.14.zip and extract the plpbt.iso and use YUMI [http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator) to put the iso on the flash drive. Once you boot the flash drive on your laptop you can select any of the partitions.

Alternatively you can download gparted live to set the boot flag on the windows partition to make it active again. You can install this to a flash drive using YUMI as well.